# HTML/Javascript Canvas drawImg Function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to mirror a section of an image, into a below canvas, of exactly the same size, based on fixed values. For example, present it a picture of a map, and mirror below in the same position and the same size a building on that original map image. However, for some unknown reason, it resizes the mirrored section every time? The only botch fix for this is to apply a multiplier to all "d" variables in the draw image function, as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Any ideas as to why this is?

Code (minus the multiplier, multipler avaliable if needed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="scream" src="image1.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="100%" height="100%">
<!--<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">-->
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

<script>
document.getElementById("scream").onload = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var imgData = document.getElementById("scream");
    c.width = imgData.width;
    c.height = imgData.height;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(c);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    console.log(img);
    //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200, 100, 143, 200, 200, 100*1.87, 143*1.87);
    //console.log(ctx);
};
</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing `width="100%" height="100%"` from the image, so it is shown at original size. Right now the browser probably scales up the image, but the copy you draw on the canvas uses the original pixels. If you want the copy to be scaled up, too, you need to calculate the scale factor dynamically by dividing the scaled up width by the image's original width.

Comment: Or simply use `img.naturalWidth`/`img.naturalHeight`

Comment: @ChrisG this worked first time! Thank you, I was stupidly thinking these were ensuring image displayed at full size but in reality was setting it to viewport height/width - if you add it as an answer I will confirm?

Comment: @Kaiido This worked too - thank you!

Comment: @ChrisG, I fail to find a correct dupe, you might want to provide an answer (you were right the browser will convert the % value to the computed px one, while drawImage use natural sizes)

Answer (score 0):

In order to mirror the image you need to translate the context `ctx.translate(0, this.height)` and then scale it `ctx.scale(1,-1);`. However on resize the canvas will stay the initial size while the image will adapt to the window size. If you need the canvas to adapt as well you will need to recalculate everything on resize.

```js
var imgData = document.getElementById("scream");
imgData.onload = function() {
    
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
 
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(c);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.translate(0, this.height);
    ctx.scale(1,-1);
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0,this.width,this.height);


};
```

```html
<img id="scream" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/imgres.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Next comes an example where the canvas size changes on resize. In this case you need to move all the code that draws the image inside a function to be called on resize.

Quote from MDN:

> Since resize events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent"

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var imgData = document.getElementById("scream");
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(c);
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  imgData.onload = function() {
    init();
  };

  function init() {
    c.width = imgData.width;
    c.height = imgData.height;

    ctx.translate(0, imgData.height);
    ctx.scale(1, -1);
    ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0, imgData.width, imgData.height);
 
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    init();

    addEventListener("resize", init, false);
  }, 15);
};
```

```html
<img id="scream" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/imgres.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: I haven't looked up ctx.translate but I will do if it means the layout will be responsive. Cheers.

Comment: I think you got confused by the use of the word "*mirror*" here. They are not trying to apply a scale(-1,0) a.k.a "*mirror effect*", but *to mirror the image in an other place*, i.e, to clone it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the *ImageElement*'s *.width* and *.height*  properties. At getting, these should return the computed value of their corresponding attribute, in *px*.
In the markup, these attributes have both been set to the relative value `100%`, which means their computed value will be relative to the ImageElement's parent's size.

So when you ask drawIamge to draw your image using these output size, it will indeed resize / stretch your image. To avoid it, you need to use the original size of the image, not of the ImageElement.

To do so, if all you need is to draw at the same size as the original image, then you can simply call the *length 3* version of `drawImage(source, x, y)`, which will use by default the *source*'s original size.
But you'll still need to resize your canvas to the correct size before doing it, and to do this, you need to access the image's original size.

Fortunately, this original size of the image, is available from the ImageElement's *naturalWidth* and *naturalHeight* properties.

```js
document.getElementById("scream").onload = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var imgData = document.getElementById("scream");
    
    console.log('computed width: ', imgData.width);
    console.log('original width: ', imgData.naturalWidth);
    
    c.width = imgData.naturalWidth;
    c.height = imgData.naturalHeight;
    var body = document.body;
    body.appendChild(c);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // the 3 length version is enough here
    ctx.drawImage(imgData, 0, 0);
};
```

```html
<img id="scream" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Edvard_Munch_-_The_Scream_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/190px-Edvard_Munch_-_The_Scream_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="100%" height="100%">
```